# What is VDSL vectoring?

Tags: router

I'm not a networking guru but I came across the term "VDSL Vectoring" while checking the FritzBox router:

[FrtizBox 7490 Details](https://en.avm.de/products/fritzbox/fritzbox-7490/details/), [FritzBox 7490 Technical Data](https://en.avm.de/products/fritzbox/fritzbox-7490/technical-data/):

> VDSL vectoring for high speeds
>
> With FRITZ!Box, you’re ready for the future: as vectoring is supported, you can reach throughput rates of up to 100 Mbit/s with standard VDSL connections and double your Internet speed without any extra hardware.

What is VDSL vectoring?

Comment: Did you check Wikipedia? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Very-high-bit-rate_digital_subscriber_line_2#Vectoring

Answer (score 1):

VDSL Vectoring is a method of increasing the speed of a given VDSL2 (G.993.2/FTTC) line so that it can achieve a higher speed than it would otherwise achieve. It does so by using noise cancelling technology to reduce interference from adjacent lines or other services or plant (equipment). Vectoring is defined by the ITU-T standard G.993.5.
More detailed information:http://www.draytek.co.uk/support/guides/kb-what-is-vdsl-vectoring-sra-and-ginp